# SQL Group by CASE result

Tags: sql, db2

I have a simple SQL query on IBM DB2. I'm trying to run something as below:

```
select case when a.custID = 42285 then 'Credit' when a.unitID <> '' then 'Sales' when a.unitID = '' then 'Refund'
else a.unitID end TYPE, sum(a.value) as Total from transactions a

group by a.custID, a.unitID
```

This query runs, however I  have a problem with `group by a.custID` - I'd prefer not to have this, but the query won't run unless it's present. I'd want to run the `group by` function based on the **result** of the `CASE` function, not the condition pool behind it. So, I'm looking something like:

```
group by TYPE
```

However adding `group by TYPE` reports an error message `"Column or global variable TYPE not found"`. Also removing `a.custID` from group section reports `"Column custID or expression in SELECT list not valid"`

Is this going to be possible at all or do I need to review my `CASE` function and avoid using the `custID` column since at the moment I'm getting a grouping also based on `custID` column, even though it's not present in `SELECT`.

I understand why the grouping works as it does, I'm just wondering if it's possible to get rid of the `custID` grouping, but still maintain it within `CASE` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want terseness of code, you could use a subquery here:

```
SELECT TYPE, SUM(value) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN a.custID = 42285 THEN 'Credit'
                WHEN a.unitID <> ''   THEN 'Sales'
                WHEN a.unitID = ''    THEN 'Refund'
                ELSE a.unitID END TYPE,
           value
    FROM transactions a
) t
GROUP BY TYPE;
```

The alternative to this would be to just repeat the `CASE` expression in the `GROUP BY` clause, which is ugly, but should still work.  Note that some databases (e.g. MySQL) have overloaded `GROUP BY` and do allow aliases to be used in at least some cases.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Grouping by the CASE expression did the trick. Will try  the subquery later on, but I have a solution in place. Have not used subqueries before, so why not wet my feet a little bit.

Comment: @sqlscholar The most performant thing would be to just repeat the `CASE` expression which appears in the `SELECT` clause, in the `GROUP BY` clause.  But, that leads to ugly (though faster) code.